# Unable to open jar file on macbook Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute

Tags: java, jar

For some reason, I am unable to open jar files on my macbook air 2013. I received the following error:

[image]

After that I opened it in the terminal and got this msg:

[image]

I am trying to follow solutions from:

[Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991936/failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute)

[Java "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute" On a any .jar file, even those that I have succeed in opening before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983422/java-failed-to-load-main-class-manifest-attribute-on-a-any-jar-file-even-tho)

but nothing has been working so far. I have updated my JDK, JRE, restarted my computer, refreshed my programs, uninstalled, re-installed, and plenty more, but nothing seems to be working...

Does anyone know how to resolve this? And also why did this happen? I have never come across this.

Comment: This JAR file is probably not meant to be run as a stand-alone program since it is a Plugin for Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Not all JAR files are executable. UnZIP it and check the manifest file.

Comment: What does your manifest file in the jar look like?

Comment: I will check. But how can I check?

Comment: Open the jar file with zip utility and locate the file META-INF/Manifest.mf

Comment: Jar files are just Zip files with some extra properties...

Comment: I see... I guess I have a lot to learn

Answer (score 1):

The jar you are attempting to run is not an executable jar. Examination of your manifest file will show that there is no Main-Class defined.

You can confirm this by opening the jar file with a zip utility (e.g. 7-zip) and locate the file META-INF/Manifest.mf.

If you want to learn about executable jar files:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/